# Código não entra no switch case?

Tags: ruby, switch

Fiquei preso nesse erro, tentei colocando `=` apenas também e nada faz o código entrar no switch case...

```
puts "Seja bem vindo ao Frutaria, qual o seu nome?"
puts "----------------------------"
nomeCliente = gets.to_s
system `clear`
puts "#{nomeCliente} temos as seguintes frutas... banana,maça e laranja!"
puts "----------------------------"
puts "Insira o número correspondente a escolha? (1) Banana (2) Maça (3) Laranja & (0) 
Sair "
puts "----------------------------"

escolha_fruta = gets.to_i

case escolha_fruta 
   when escolha_fruta == 1
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a banana é R$ 11 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 2
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a maça é R$ 5 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 3
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a laranja é R$ 8 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 0
      "Até mais #{nomeCliente},volte sempre!"
   else
      "Nao compreendi a sua escolha..."
   end
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 4):

**Caso geral (Com parametro)**

A estrutura `case` do ruby deve ser do seguinte formato:

```rb
case escolha_fruta
when 1 
  #Executa este bloco quando escolha_fruta for 1
when 2..6
  #Quando escolha_fruta for de 2 até 6
else
  #quando escolha_fruta for qualquer outra coisa
end
```

Perceba que após when se espera um valor que a variável referenciada em case (escolha_fruta) possa representar.

**Seu caso (Sem parametro)**

Vc pode usar a estrutura como um if/else (como vc está fazendo) mas **não** dê um parametro para case, logo:

Onde está:

`case escolha_fruta`

Deixe apenas:

`case`

Veja seu código:

```rb
case
   when escolha_fruta == 1
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a banana é R$ 11 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 2
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a maça é R$ 5 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 3
      "#{nomeCliente} o valor a laranja é R$ 8 reais!"
   when escolha_fruta == 0
      "Até mais #{nomeCliente},volte sempre!"
   else
      "Nao compreendi a sua escolha..."
   end
```

**Extra**

Veja mais detalhes em:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente como o [GUILearn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/194582/guilearn) abordou, você deveria retirar a variável quando abordar o case. Além disso, poderia optar por seguir uma ordem crescente de situacoes.

```ruby
case escolha_fruta
when 1
  puts "#{nomeCliente} o valor a banana é R$ 11 reais!"
when 2
  puts "#{nomeCliente} o valor a maça é R$ 5 reais!"
when 3
  puts "#{nomeCliente} o valor a laranja é R$ 8 reais!"
when 0
  puts "Até mais #{nomeCliente},volte sempre!"
else
  'Nao compreendi a sua escolha...'
end
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).